# Variable Leading Zeros (Number Formatting)

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a list of values in column A ranging from 1-1000, how can I format the column so each value is '0000' ie. based on len(max(A:A)) which would be 4. This would need to be dependent on the max value.

If the max in column A was 10,500, I would want every value to have a format '00000'. Any way to automatically set this - either in VBA or another formatting method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("A2:A10").NumberFormat="00000"
```

should do it. For more dynamic, something like:

```
set rng = Range("A2:A10")
rng.NumberFormat = Left("0000000000000", len(application.max(rng)))
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if the max value was 1,000,000. In that case, I would want the number format to be "000000000". Number of 0's needs to be dependent on the max value of the column

Comment: then find out the max, and use its LEN() !

Comment: Thank you. the dynamic recommendation worked!

Comment: It will work only for numbers smaller than `9999999999999`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub example()
    ' define the location/column
    Dim Location As Range
    Set Location = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    
    ' get the amount of digits the maximum number has
    Dim Digits As Long
    Digits = Len(CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Location)))
    
    ' set the number format of the location to the amount of digits
    Location.NumberFormat = String(Digits, "0")
    
End Sub
```

or even better write a generic procedure that you can re-use with any range:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetNumberFormatToMaxDigits(ByVal Location As Range)
    Dim Digits As Long
    Digits = Len(CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Location)))
    
    Location.NumberFormat = String(Digits, "0")
End Sub
```

and just call it like

```
SetNumberFormatToMaxDigits ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
```

Comment: I like the use of `String()`. Nice. Don't see it that often.

Answer (score 0):

To set your NumberFormat to have Leading Zeros in VBA, you can use `Range.NumberFormat="0…0"` So, 4 zeros would be`Range.NumberFormat="0000"`, 5 zeros would be`Range.NumberFormat="00000"`, etc.

To dynamically create the correct number of zeros, we can use the `String` function.  For example, `Range.NumberFormat = String(4, "0")` for 4 zeroes, or  `Range.NumberFormat = String(5, "0")` for 5 zeroes.

To count the maximum length of text in a range, we can use the `SUMPRODUCT`, `MAX`, and `LEN` Worksheet Functions: `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(LEN(A:A)))`.  To ensure that this is always at least 4, we include 4 in the `MAX`: `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(4, LEN(A:A)))`.

To use that in VBA, we can pass it to the `Evaluate` function of the Worksheet.  For example, if the column is in `Sheet1`, then you can use `Sheet1.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(MAX(4, LEN(A:A)))")` to get the maximum length of that column.  (If you have headers, you might need to specify your data more exactly than just `A:A` for the entire column — or ensure that the header is 4 characters or fewer!)

And, combining everything into a neat little bit of code for a Range:

```
'Define Range however you want
Dim Target AS Range
Set Target = Sheet1.Columns(1)

'Set the NumberFormat
With Target
    .NumberFormat = String(.Worksheet.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(MAX(4,LEN(" & .Address() & ")))"), "0")
End With
```

Comment: why the expensive sumproduct? You just take the length of the max number. That is the one that has the most digits. And you calculate the length only of one number instead of thousands.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Mostly because I defaulted to code that would work for alphanumeric entries, rather than purely numeric